# "Save As" window does not pop up immediately after sending a file download request(HTTP GET)

Tags: java, spring, file, http, download

I am using **HttpServletResponse** to implement a method for file download. After I send a file download request from the front web page, the "Save As" window does not pop up immediately. Instead, it seems that after part of the file is cached, then the "Save As" window pops up.

For example, if the size of the file to be downloaded is 67.5MB, when the "Save As" window shows up, I click the "save" button, then the download progress the browser(chrome) shows has already become 15.9/67.5MB. And then the progress shows 31.8/67.5MB, 47.8/67.5MB, 63.7/67.5MB, 67.5/67.5MB.

If the size of the file to be downloaded is less then 15.9MB, after a while, when the "Save As" window shows up, I click the "save" button, then the browser(chrome) directly saves the entire file to disk, it seems the entire file has already been cached once the "Save As" window shows up.

The javascript code on the front web page used to send download request:

```
   window.parent.location.target = "_blank";
   window.parent.location.href = url;
```

Part of the code for file download on the backend:

```
    // the type of response is HttpServletResponse
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" 
                     URLEncoder.encode(gridFSFile.getFilename(), "UTF-8"));
    response.addHeader("Content-Length", "" + gridFSFile.getLength());
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8");

    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int bytesRead = -1;
    while((bytesRead = downloadStream.read(buffer)) != -1 ) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    os.flush();

    downloadStream.close();
    os.close();
```

Comment: What is the value of bufferSize? When does the first call to os.write() happen on the server, compared to the instant when the popup opens?

Comment: Seems like this is how the browser handles file downloads and would be outside of your control.

Comment: The value of bufferSize is 261120. If the size of the file to be downloaded is 67.5MB, when I use "step over" to debug on the backend code , after the first time the `os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)` was executed, the "Save As" window pops up immediately. But if it's not in debug mode, the "Save As" window shows up after the 64th time the `os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)` was executed. @JBNizet

Comment: Then it seems indeed that this behavior is outside your control.